# In async Rust, how can a Future make sure it only calls the most recent Waker?

Tags: rust, async-await, future

The purpose of this question is to understand how Futures are supposed to work in Rust. I do not have a specific piece of code that does not work, but rather a problem understanding how Futures must be written to fulfil their contract.

Suppose you are writing a Future. The contract for poll() allows the caller to pass a different Waker each time, and the Future should only call the most recent one.

Suppose that the Future hides actual work that is done in the background by a worker thread. If the worker is not yet done with the work that was passed to it when the Future was created, the future should return Pending and clone and store the Waker. The Future then does nothing for some time and it is the worker thread that has to call the Waker. This will cause the Future to be polled again.

Suppose that when the Future gets polled again, it decides that what the worker thread has done so far is not sufficient, so it returns Pending again, and also clones and stores the new Waker it gets on this second call.

Since it is the worker thread that actually calls the Waker, the poll() implementation has to update the Waker in the background thread. However, it is unclear to me how the poll() implementation can even do this in a race condition free way -- but now it gets tricky, because the details depend on the fine print in the poll() contract to such an extent that, I think, this fine print isn't even specified exactly.

One possible thing that could happen is that while poll() is running, just before it wants to hand over the new Waker to the background worker, the worker decides it is time to call the Waker. It now calls the *old* Waker, even though poll() has already received a new Waker, which may or may not violate the contract (this isn't specified, I think). One might therefore think that the worker may call the old Waker until poll() has finished, but this only works if the worker is allowed to call *either* Waker while poll() is running, which again isn't mentioned, and is only required to call the new Waker after poll() has returned.

Finally, even this assumption depends on another unspecified thing: The exact meaning of "after poll() has returned" in a multi-threading context, which usually has to resort to specially-defined terms such as happens-after to even define that one thing happens after another thing.

Given all this, how can a poll() implementation fulfil its contract to only call the latest Waker? Is there a document that specifies all the details that seem to be missing from the poll() documentation?

Comment: I think the best you can practically do is the following: Store the waker in a Mutex. Lock the Mutex as the first operation in `poll`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding updating the waker in a race-free way, my suggestion is to use [`futures::task::AtomicWaker`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/task/struct.AtomicWaker.html), which can store and wake a waker atomically.

Something to be aware of is that a waker being woken does not mean that there is more work to be done on a future, and wakers are allowed to be woken sporadically (for example if a different future is ready to progress).

With this in mind, let's consider a simple future with an `AtomicWaker` and a "work to be done" flag that's shared between the future and a worker thread. If the "work to be done" flag is not set when polled, the future will simply return `Poll::Pending`.

For correctness, we only need two things:

1. The worker thread must set the "work to be done" flag before it wakes the waker.
2. The future must register a new waker before it checks the "work to be done" flag.

This means that no matter in which order the worker and `poll` method do operations, the behavior will be correct:

1. If the `poll` method is not called, then the worker will set the flag and wake the waker, which will poll the future which will see that there is work to be done.
2. If the `poll` method is called, and the waker is woken before the new waker is registered, then the future will see that there is work to be done, and the waker can be disregarded. (This may cause the old waker to be woken unnecessarily, but that's fine.)
3. If the `poll` method is called, and the waker is woken after the new waker is registered, then the future may or may not see that there is work to be done. If it does, then the waker can be disregarded as in #2; if not, then the waker will ensure the future is polled again as in #1.

In all three cases, when the worker thread marks the future as ready to do more work and wakes the waker, the future will be polled until it has done more work, even if that may require being polled more than one time.

Comment: I think both answers are actually describing the same solution, but this one spells them out more explicitly, both in referring to AtomicWaker and in how the flag is checked after a new Waker was registered (because in practice it's probably poll() and not the background worker who is going to do that, and poll() can then just perform the necessary resulting steps instead of waking up itself).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the documentation could be clearer about exactly what is required. However, practically, all you need is to **make sure that the new waker *is* invoked, not necessarily that the old waker *isn't* invoked.** That is, it's okay to either wake **both** wakers, or wake only the most recent one, so you don't need to have any specific inter-thread event timing relationship.

Why can we conclude that? Because of these two facts:

1. There is no rule against polling a future even when it has not woken. (For example, this *must* happen whenever responsibility for polling a future has been handed to a new/different executor task, because the waker needs to be provided to the future.) Therefore, no future can know that it was polled spuriously rather than usefully.
2. `Future`s are opaque. They're supposed to invoke wakers “once the future can make progress”, but from the outside you cannot tell whether they *actually* made progress. Therefore, the executor of the future cannot know whether a given wake and poll was useful or spurious.

Putting these two facts together, we can conclude that the only consequence of mis-directed `Waker::wake()` calls is a little wasted CPU time.

So in your worker thread situation, the important thing is that if the background thread is handed a new waker, and it believes the result is ready, then *it should immediately invoke that waker* (as opposed to assuming polling will happen because it invoked a previous waker). It may or may not have also woken a previous, obsolete waker at the moment it became ready, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: This does help, but I think not with the situation in which the worker still has the old Waker and calls that. Still helpful, though.

Comment: @MartinGeisse As I say in the last paragraph, the worker is obligated to invoke the new waker, too, as soon as it hears about it.

Comment: Ah, I totally misunderstood that. Now it makes sense to me. Thank you very much!